# How to custom a class adopt UIDynamicItem by swift

Tags: ios, swift

In Objective-C, we can custom a object by adopt UIDynamicItem protocol，like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LCDynamicItem : NSObject  <UIDynamicItem>
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint center;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGRect bounds;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGAffineTransform transform;

@end
```

**but how can I use it in swift.**

I don't know, Someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In swift your code will be

```
class LCDynamicItem: NSObject, UIDynamicItem {
    var center: CGPoint
    var bounds: CGRect {
        get {
            return self.bounds
        }
    }

    var transform: CGAffineTransform
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry for a long time to reply you.
I find a way  like this, but `bounds` is return `{0,0,1,1}`:

```class LCDynamicItem: NSObject, UIDynamicItem { 
    //MARK: UIDynamicItem protocol
    var center: CGPoint = CGPointZero
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    var bounds: CGRect
    override init() {
        self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
    }
}

```

Comment: I didn't get the problem with this solution.

Comment: Only have this problem in objective-c